# Div Floats and Clears : Multiple Elements

Tags: html, css

I Need the right Column elements to be flush with the javascript back button image. Not sure what the deal is, I have tried clear left, clear right, and clear both.

Live Example:
http://newsite.702wedding.com/las-vegas-marriage.asp

Any Help Would be Great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code which looks like this:

```
<div class="package-back-button1"><a href="las-vegas-wedding-packages.asp"></a></div>
<div class="clearfloat-left"></div>
<div class="win-this-package1"><a href="wedding-honeymoon-las-vegas.asp"></a></div>
```

into this:

```
<div style="float: left">
    <div class="package-back-button1"><a href="las-vegas-wedding-packages.asp"></a></div>
    <div class="win-this-package1"><a href="wedding-honeymoon-las-vegas.asp"></a></div>
</div>
```

So, remove the `.clearfloat-left` div, and enclose the two items inside a `div` with `float: left`.

---

<strike>A kinda yucky (but easy) fix is to do this:</strike>

- On `.package-right-box1`, add `margin-top: -89px`.

Tested in Firefox, IE7/8.

Comment: I dont think that one will work because we have these pages. http://newsite.702wedding.com/cheap-las-vegas-weddings.asp

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I'll edit with a more robust method.

Comment: Done[.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084401/div-floats-and-clears-multiple-elements/5084497#5084497)

Comment: @Varazi: To make my second fix work in IE, you also need to add `width: 48%` to the new div. Sorry, forgot to test it in IE before.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a solution on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4abB/1/).  Code is below.

```
<!--Left Column Boxes-->
<div style="width:50%; float:left">
  <div style="background-color:#f00; width:100%">left1</div>
  <div style="background-color:#0f0; width:100%;">left2</div>
  <div style="background-color:#00f; width:100%;">left3</div>
</div>

<!--Right Column Boxes-->
<div style="float:right; width:50%">
  <div style="background-color:#aaa; width:100%;">right1<br />
    <div style="background-color:#ff0; width:100%;">right2</div>
  </div>

  <div style="background-color:#0ff; width:100%;">right3</div>
</div>
```

Also, be aware that your second div on the right was nested within the top-right div.  I'm not sure that was intended, but am just pointing it out.